# Different credentials on different computers git

Tags: database, git

I have been working on a system to push changes from my git repository to a live site.  The issue is that on my local box (where only I have access) I leave db credentials defaults; but I don't want them to be defaults on the web.

What would be the best solution to have a few files that are only located on each development computer, and are never uploaded/committed, etc.  I was thinking of throwing in an example file if anyone clones it down, that way they'd know how to create the real credentials file.

I'm pretty new to git, and so I don't think I have the experience to really come up with a good solution for this, so any help would be great.
Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of committing an examples file and then not actually tracking the real file is a good one.

Just put the name of the real file in `.gitignore` so that no one will add it by accident.

Comment: So if I pushed my changes to a remote repository, and I left the a file in the working-tree of that repository (that isn't tracked by anyone else) it wouldn't be deleted?

Comment: Nevermind, I just used a post-receive hook to cp over a directory of computer specifc settings after it checked it out